# Gradle sync error when adding Material Spinner dependency

Tags: android, github, gradle, build, android-spinner

When trying to add the dependency for the latest version (2.0.0) of the [Material Spinner](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner), my gradle sync fails with the error:

```
Error:(33, 14) Failed to resolve: com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0
```

This is my build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myroommate.myroommate"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile ('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
}
```

But when I change the [Material Spinner version to 1.1.1](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner/tree/1.1.1), the gradle sync is finishing without any errors.

```
compile ('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Even using 1.1.2 makes my gradle build fails. I would like to use the latest version of the Material Spinner so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the release has not been pushed to maven yet.
It'll be ok very soon.
check [this](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner/issues/105)

Comment: Thank you. Didn't realize 1.1.2 and 2.0.0 were released 2 days ago. I shall wait